# Combining models trained on different shapes of input to predict same output

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear, ensemble-learning

Sorry in advance if this is obvious

I have two features, one of shape (6075) and the other is (366).

I've trained two models:

```
# Split A set
X_A_train, X_A_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(A_values, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Split B set
X_B_train, X_B_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(B_values, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Model A
model_A_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf')
model_A_svr.fit(A_X_train, Y_train)

# Model B
model_B_svr = SVR(kernel='rbf',degree=10)
model_B_svr.fit(B_X_train, Y_train)
```

I wanted to create an ensemble of these two models say using a [VoterRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.predict). Is it possible to combine these two models and make predictions with their inputs?

Something like:

```
ensemble = VotingRegressor(estimators=[('A Model', model_A_svr ), ('BModel', model_B_svr )], weights=[2,1])

ensemble.fit([X_A_train, X_B_train], Y_train)

predictions = ensemble.predict([X_A_test, X_B_test])

print_score(predictions, y_test)
```

This throws an error:

```
ensemble.fit([X_A_train, X_B_train], Y_train)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4800,6075) into shape (4800)
```

Does this make sense?